# What the difference to access from inner class or method?

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

Hi sorry for may be stupid question I'm just really interested.
The compiler says

> Variable 'resMessage' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be final or effectively final

And underlines it with red, while its sibling 'name' lives and works fine. Why is that?

```
btGoOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String resMessage = "";
        String email = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String name = etName.getText().toString().trim();
        String name1 = etName.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();
            
        if (!validateEmail() | !validateName() | !validatePassword()){
            // do nothing (input errors are handled in validation functions
        } else  {
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> taskAddUser) {
                    if (taskAddUser.isSuccessful()) {
                        resMessage = name + " " + getString(R.string.msg_user_signed_up);
                        auth.getCurrentUser().sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> taskVerifSent) {
                                if (taskVerifSent.isSuccessful()) {
                                    resMessage += " " + getString(R.string.msg_user_verif_sent);
                                } else {
                                    resMessage += " " + getString(R.string.msg_user_verif_not_sent);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        Log.d(TAG, resMessage);
                        Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, resMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        // TODO: 12.10.2023 fill with extras...
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        resMessage = name + " " + getString(R.string.msg_user_signed_up_failed) + taskAddUser.getException().getMessage();
                        Log.d(TAG, resMessage);
                        Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, resMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This 'resMessage' variables were just temporary sacks for gathering text, so when I tried to make one at the level of common block (btGoOn.setOnClickListener) I've got this error.

Yes, I made web search and [this is a most close question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76497086/why-compiler-forces-to-use-atomic-variable-inside-foreach-loop-in-java) -- I might get the same if I went to lambda-expressions (but I didn't). And there are some advices to move the variable on the top level of class's fields. huh this is not a field this is just temporary sack!.
Also I may accept the Android Studio offer and switch to such I'd say ugly code:

```
final String[] resMessage = {""};
...
    resMessage[0] = name + " " + getString(R.string.msg_user_signed_up);
//...
    Log.d(TAG, resMessage[0]);
    Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, resMessage[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

But why the compiler disallows one variable and allow another**?

Comment: `getText().toString()` is double talk. It’s already a `String`.

Comment: @user207421 at this particular example you maybe right but strictly saying `getText()` returns an `Editable` what is not exactly the `String`. [Here is details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31169001/20456581).

Comment: If there had been any information in your post that you were using `Editable` you might have a point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the compiler error for `resMessage` because you're modifying it within the inner class. It needs to be `final` or effectively final (unchanged after initialization) due to how Java's scoping and lifetime rules work for anonymous inner classes. This is because the inner class instance may outlive the method where it is defined, leading to unpredictable behavior.

The `name` variable is not modified within the inner class, so it is effectively final, hence no error.

Comment: Wow, @marcin-orlowski that's exactly I was looking for -- the _strange_ behaviour of `name`. (Of course I'd better to avoid that _strange_ `resMessage[0]` but it's already another question). Thanks!